# Simple formula or full function

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

first of all let me say that my knowledge of Excel is somewhat basic. I know about formulas but not indepth. I know about functions but nothing about programing. That being said, on with my question.

I'm currently building a office hockey pool spread sheet. I have my main sheet, the result of the games and the differential (see link above for reference, text is in french sorry about that). I will have another sheet, prediction sheet, that the participant will fill with their prediction about who's gonna win the game and by how many points (differential).

Now, I need the prediction sheet to calculate the points attribution depending on the prediction.

Here's how it's supposed to calculate:

1 point for winning team prediction (per game)
1 point for good differential (no mather what team won)
2 point if differential is 3 or higher.

User predictions go on "prediction" sheet, they input what they think the diff. will be on the same side as the team they pick to win.

So what I want to know is, what would be the best way to go about this, with a formula or with a custom function in VBA? I need to determine 1: if the prediction is in the same cell as the other sheet and 2: if the differential is the same as the game result.

Ok, re-reading this I know it's kind of confusing, but it's clear in my head... sorry about that. If anyone of you can make sence out of my problem, please help me by guiding me in the right way. Thank you very much.

Comment: I need to confirm, each person has their own prediction sheet in the same workbook? Also I don't know anything about hockey, so your sheets don't mean a lot to me. Are there 8 matches in the first round? I noticed a match (what I think is a match anyway) has 7 boxes for each team, are they breaks in a match. I'd like to help but maybe my lack of experience in Hockey would be a problem lol

Comment: Hi Rob, yes, every participant will have a prediction sheet of their own in the same workbook. The first round has 8 teams playing, the first team to reach 4 games won goes on to the 2nd round. They have a max of 7 matches to reach 4 games won. No match can be a tie. Thanks for trying to help :)

Answer (score 0):

If found part of my solution.

I used this formula (I know it can be shorter and better but that's the extent of my knowledge in excel):

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(COMPILATION!A4);ISBLANK(COMPILATION!A5));0;IF(OR(A4=ABS(COMPILATION!A4-COMPILATION!A5);A5=ABS(COMPILATION!A4-COMPILATION!A5));IF(OR(A4>=3;A5>=3);2;1);0))
```